# How to show new apps update during launch of an application in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I noticed in a few Apps during launch they are displaying all their previous and latest Apps in an activity (but that doesn't seem like a main Activity). On click of a close button the actual application starts. I find that as a good marketing strategy. I want to implement such a thing so that I can update my new apps in the released apps automatically. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That must be a splash screen implementation
check this out

http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html